# pathForResource method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

[image]I'm playing around with imageView and there is the method [ imageWithContentsOfFile];
But actually it doesn't show anything after run it. Below the code , there is the [ imageNamed:] method and it works as usual.
Any ideas?
Thanks,

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController2


- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    // just fugly don't do it

//    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stanford"]];


    UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;




    NSString *imgPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"google" ofType:@"png"];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];


   // self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"google"];


}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@end
```

I guess the problem is pathForResource method doesn't work properly somehow...

Comment: What's the extension of your image 'google'.. If your image reads 'google.png'.. then, the imgPath should be correct..

Comment: Is the name of image exactly "google.png"?

Comment: its extension is .png, but as I dragged it into the images.xcassets , the .png is disappeared.

Comment: If the image does not have an extension, then you can pass 'nil' to the ofType

Comment: @Genie Wanted : thanks, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS 7+, and using Asset Catalogs (which it looks like you're using, since you specified images.xcassets in one of your comments), Xcode 5 now puts the assets into a new file format. 1 file for all of the assets. This means you can not get access to the file directly using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. And that's also why `pathForResource:ofType:` doesn't return a path.

If you need to access the file directly, you can include it as an normal image outside of an asset catalog.

You should also ask yourself if you need to access the file directly. In most cases you can use `imageNamed:`. Which also gives you automatic caching for the image and can improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakPoint to check "imgPath" result. If is empty, maybe you should add @2x to name:

NSString *imgPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"google@2x" ofType:@"png"];

Comment: thanks, I did it with the break point as you said, and it always says nil.

Comment: So that's problem of path, change to @"google@2x", path is nil also?

Comment: yeah it's still nil... :((   pathForResource method doesn't work somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I ignore your screenshot. From the screenshot, you picture is from desktop, put it in your project document, add again, the problem will fix.

Answer (score 0):

-- > Right click on the image in project Navigator

-- > Show in finder

-- > Right click on the image in finder

-- > Get info

-- > Look for file name and extension.

-- > Give the same name and extension in the your project. It would work.